# select html element id using jquery and .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have several `<select>` boxes all using the same prefix and I would like to set up a recursive function to essentially do the work for me.

```
$('[id^="by_"]').change(function(e)
            {
                var elem = e;
                console.log(e.value);
            });
```

Based on this code is my intention pretty clear? Am I on the right track?

console prints out: `undefined`

Comment: Is there some problem with the working .. ??

Comment: I think you're on the right track - the selector you're using matches a prefix of "by_", and you're binding the `change` event to all of them. Make sure you put this in `$(document).ready` or similar. Are you having any problems with this code? Instead of using the `e` parameter, you can also just use `this` inside of the function to refer to the element and `$(this)` to get the jQuery object of it.

Comment: @ianpgall that is just what I needed! Can you add this an an answer so I can vote it up please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track - the selector you're using matches a prefix of "by_", and you're binding the change event to all of them. Make sure you put this in `$(document).ready` or similar. Are you having any problems with this code? Instead of using the `e` parameter, I would just use `this` inside of the function to refer to the element and `$(this)` to get the jQuery object of it. So to get the value, you'd use:

```
this.value
// or
$(this).val()
```

(ignore the `e` and `elem` stuff, although it wouldn't be a bad idea to store `$(this)` in something like `elem` so you can have a reference to it instead of re-creating the jQuery object every time you need it)

When using callbacks to events with jQuery, the (first) parameter of the callback is an `event` object that explains many things about the event that occurred ( http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/ ) and does not hold the element - that's what `this` is for!

Answer (score 1):

`e` in your code is the event object which has no `value` property, you should use `this` instead:

```
$('[id^="by_"]').change(function(e) {
     var elem = this;
     console.log(this.value);
});
```

Or if you want to use `event` object, you can use `target` property:

```
e.target.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, why not something like this:

```
$('[id^="by_"]').change(function(e)
{
    var $elem = $( this );
    console.log( $elem.val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it more something like that:

```
$('[id^="by_"]').change(function()
            {
                console.log($('option:selected',this).val());
            });
​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk5wF/2/)

Comment: Not necessary - `$(this).val()` holds the currently selected value. If you needed to get the text of the `option` or something, you might need something like this. But obviously this still does work